# Access violation for mat.at<short>(x,y)

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

For a simple vector that I have

```
Mat m = Mat(1, vectorLength, CV_16S, short(0));
```

I try to update a value with the following line

```
m.at<short>(0,0) = 10000*value;
```

But .at(0,0) keeps giving me access violation.

Is this a possible bug in opencv3 ?

Comment: Have you tried the same code using OpenCV v2.x?

Comment: I am using the OpenCV 3.0.0 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably in your mat construction (but is first recognized in `.get`, where the data you want to access isn't present):

use instead:

```
Mat m = Mat(1, vectorLength, CV_16S, cv::Scalar(0));
```

or

```
Mat m = Mat::zeros(1, vectorLength, CV_16S);
```

In your version it interprets short(0) as address where referenced data is assumed. So it probably uses this Mat constructor there: `Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void* data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)` where `void* data` is `short(0)` instead of this constructor, which you probably wanted to call: `Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, const Scalar& s)`

But maybe I'm wrong, then you probably want to use this instead:

`Mat m = Mat(1, vectorLength, CV_16S, yourVector.data());`

in this case, the matrix doesn't allocate own memory but instead just links to the vector's data.

Comment: Correct! My bad that was a critical error! It makes sense. I may have mixed up initialization with double(0.0) as I read somewhere to initialize the matrix.